# How do I parse a remote page for images using the name attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-parsing

Due to the circumstances of an internal site setup, I am trying to parse a series of images from a local page and have the image information passed to another local page by matching the name attribute to an article name. I'm looking for the src and class attributes of the images.

The 2 pages reside on the same domain but one page contains a series of images, the other page contains our standard page layout that is going to be styled with a combination of JS and CSS. The image containing page is more like a repository for a series of images.

Note: I know that this could be achieved very easy if we were to use the server side, but due to the circumstances of this setup, we have to come up with something on the front end.

The end result would be a listing on the main page with the respective images from the repo page placed next to each article listing.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!-- HTML ON IMAGE REPO PAGE -->
<img src="/path/to/my/image/repo/image_01.jpg" name="article_01" />
<img src="/path/to/my/image/repo/image_02.gif" name="article_02" />
<img src="/path/to/my/image/repo/image_03.png" name="article_03" />
<img src="/path/to/my/image/repo/image_04.jpg" name="article_04" />
<img src="/path/to/my/image/repo/image_05.gif" name="article_05" />
<img src="/path/to/my/image/repo/image_06.jpg" name="article_06" />

<!-- HTML ON MAIN PAGE -->
... HTML code blah blah blah ...
<div class="imageCnt">
    <div class="listItem"><a href="/path/to/my/article_01.html">Cool Article 1</a></div>
    <div class="listItem"><a href="/path/to/my/article_02.html">Cool Article 2</a></div>
    <div class="listItem"><a href="/path/to/my/article_03.html">Cool Article 3</a></div>
    <div class="listItem"><a href="/path/to/my/article_04.html">Cool Article 4</a></div>
    <div class="listItem"><a href="/path/to/my/article_05.html">Cool Article 5</a></div>
    <div class="listItem"><a href="/path/to/my/article_06.html">Cool Article 6</a></div>
</div>
... HTML code blah blah blah ...


<!-- JS ON MAIN PAGE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageContainer = "/path/to/image/page_2.html";
    var imageFileSrc;

    imageFileSrc = $.post(imageContainer); // Thought it best to store posted page data in a variable

    $('.imageCnt').find('a').each(function(index) {

        // First, get the article name
        var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href').split("/");
        var articleUrl = thisUrl[3].split(".");
        articleName = articleUrl[0];

        // Then, find the image based on the name
        var imageSrc = $("[name*="+articleName+"]"); // This is where I'm lost!? :)
    });

});
</script>
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify:

```
var imageSrc = $('img[name="'+articleName+'"]');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this only the selector portion of the script. I also need to figure out the parsing of the image repo page.

Answer (score 0):

never tried it, but this may seem to work...

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/link-to-another-page-and-execute-jquery-there
(this is just a link)

EDIT:
also you could try something like:

```
$.get('filename.html', function(data) {
$('.class_name',data).html(); //returns the HTML of .class_name inside of filename.html
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: hmmm, it is a link to another page resource though, not sure if you can bring the images to your page.

Comment: also, you may want to check this plugin...
http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/

EDIT: it runs on the server :S

Comment: Thanks hagensoft, I'll have to give this a spin when I get into the office tomorrow. I think you're solution may work, but I can't say for sure until I'm behind a firewall.

Comment: Cool, if it fails you can also try something like: 
$("imageCnt").load("http://www.yoursite.com/index.html #image");

Note: there is a browser policy that you cannot get data from a remote domain unless its in JSON format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an error in selecting your url path to get the file name, you did `thisUrl[3]` which should be `thisUrl[4]`

Try this

```
$('.imageCnt').find('a').each(function(index) {

        // First, get the article name
        var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href').split("/");
        var articleUrl = thisUrl[4].split(".");
        articleName = articleUrl[0];

        // Then, find the image based on the name
        var imageSrc = $("img[name="+articleName+"]").attr('src'); // This is where I'm lost!? :)
    alert(imageSrc);
    });
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMz3Q/)

Comment: hsalama, thanks for the response, but the index is not the issue here. I'm actually using a totally different URL structure for the variable thisURL on the site where this code will be used, but I have to mask it this way for security/confidentiality reasons. :)

Comment: @dnyce still, if you use the above it should work, I just made a note about the index since when I was testing it was returning the wrong thing.

Comment: This won't work because it does not take into consideration the image repo page. That code does not reside on the same page as the article code. That's the tricky part. Parsing image/code found on another page. I think we're close to a solution though.